# Displaying list of visits—ListView or Table?

Tags: mobile, flutter

I'm working on my first app in Flutter and running into a dilemma. I'd like to display a list of visits.

I would display the name of the client that's been visited on the left, and some statistics (hours worked for example) on the right.

With my knowledge of HTML/CSS I'd say put it in a table. But there seem to be some limitations for Table widgets in Flutter..

- Not clickable
- They don't scroll by default (as far as I know)
- No support for headers

Frankly I'm confused. The Table widget seems to lack some functionality and I might be better off using the ListView widget. However, then I'd have to set fixed column-widths myself to align the cells properly..

What do you recommend I use for this now?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're describing it makes it sound a lot more complicated than it is to implement in Flutter.

All you need is a list view with your items in a row. The container and the list will fill the screen. You don't have to set any fixed column widths.

If you use the following code you'll see a list of 10 children with text next to each other.

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (buildContext, int) => Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Sites visited'),
                    Text('Hours worked')
                  ],),
                    height: 60.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))))
```

If you want touch functionality on any of the items wrap it in a GesureDetector and then listen to which ever gesture you want, tap, double tap, or any of the other options.